# Is there any non written rule that an associatedtype shouldn't be constrained by a concrete type?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols, design-principles, associated-types

```
class Human {
    var name : String?
}

class Man : Human {
    var numberOfWallets : Int?
}

class Woman : Human {
    var numberOfPurses : Int?
}

protocol P {
    associatedtype Person : Human
    func printX(of person : Person)
    func printY(of person: Person)
}
```

Which allows `Human` to be its `typealias`:

```
class C : P {
    typealias Person = Human
    func printX(of person: Human) {
        print(person.numberOfCars)
    }

    func printY(of person: Human) {
        print(person.name)
    }
}
```

As you can see the `Person` type is constrained by `Human` which itself is a concrete type. I'm wondering if this is common. My intuition tells me that it's actually a sign that I shouldn't be use protocols, and rather classes itself are just fine.

or I should just do

```
protocol P {
    associatedtype Person
    func printX(of person : Person)
    func printY(of person: Person)
}

class C : P {
    func printX(of person: Man) {
        print(person.numberOfCars)
    }

    func printY(of person: Man) {
        print(person.name)
    }
}
```

Which won't allow a `Woman` & `Man` instanced to be simultaneously used against a `C` instance.

I know it depends on what I want to do. But my question really is: Is constraining an asscoiatedtype with a concrete type ever meaningful?!

Or associatedtypes are just there to be either unconstrained or constrained by a protocol, not a concrete type...

Comment: They're probably not as common as a protocol-constrained associated types, but class-constrained associated types definitely have valid use cases, in the same way that class-constrained generic placeholders have valid use cases.

Comment: So to answer my own question: It's fine to do such. The reason I thought this might not be ok is because I'm new to using PATs and most of Swift documentation is where they are constrained to another protocol. ie I haven't come across an associatedtype constrained by a concrete type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
 associatedtype Person : Human
```

The constraint is not concrete or not. It works in parallel fashion for both kinds of inheritance.

• If Human is a protocol, Person must be a concrete type that *adopts* it.

• If Human is a class, Person must be a concrete type that *descends* from it.

Both are useful and legal, and very similar to one another.

Comment: You're explaining what the `:` does. inherits or adopts. My question: Is it common to have your associatedtype based off a concrete type? Have you see instances in Swift/Apple code where they constraint it with a concrete type? Because I haven't seen any...

Comment: Swift standard library is all structs (and protocols) so obviously you wouldn’t see class constraints.

Comment: an example of a struct constraint would also suffice to nullify my claim. I mean isn't struct also a concrete type?

Comment: No that would make no sense and isn’t legal.  Constraints with a colon, as I said in my answer, are about inheritance. Classes and protocols do inheritance, by descent and adoption respectively. Structs don’t.